# Hibernate and DOUBLE in Oracle 11g

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm porting an application written for Sybase and Hibernate 3.6.4 to start using Oracle 11g. As I understand people were able to get Hibernate working with Oracle 11g using Oracle10gDialect. I'm using that but for one of the columns which is mapped java.lang.Double I'm having issues.

When I create the table with the column as BINARY_DOUBLE, hibernate complains saying:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in
>   TEST_SCHEMA.TEST_TABLE for column PERCENTAGE. Found: binary_double,
>   expected: double precision

and when I define the column as DOUBLE PRCEISION, it complains saying:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in
>   TEST_SCHEMA.TEST_TABLE for column PERCENTAGE. Found: float, expected:
>   double precision

Looking at the docs both of these errors make sense because there's no Double data type in Oracle. But looking at the Dialect code, I'm not sure why I'm seeing the second error.

Class org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect has this method which has "double precision" mapped to Types.DOUBLE

```
protected void registerNumericTypeMappings() {
    registerColumnType( Types.BIT, "number(1,0)" );
    registerColumnType( Types.BIGINT, "number(19,0)" );
    registerColumnType( Types.SMALLINT, "number(5,0)" );
    registerColumnType( Types.TINYINT, "number(3,0)" );
    registerColumnType( Types.INTEGER, "number(10,0)" );

    registerColumnType( Types.FLOAT, "float" );
    registerColumnType( Types.DOUBLE, "double precision" );
    registerColumnType( Types.NUMERIC, "number($p,$s)" );
    registerColumnType( Types.DECIMAL, "number($p,$s)" );
}
```

So, I'm not sure why DOUBLE PRECISION is not working for me. Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong here. I'm sure those who have tested Oracle11gDialect would have used Double in their code.

Thanks,
K.

Comment: `PRCEISION` is a typo here? `@Column(precision=10, scale=2) BigDecimal percentage;`

Comment: True its a typo just in the question. The table is successfully created in oracle.

Comment: This problem comes only in validate mode of Grails. We can remove this error by following this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59407175/5068213

Answer (score 1):

When you define a column with `DOUBLE PRECISION` Oracle automatically converts it to `FLOAT` which could be verified with the SQL statement `DESCRIBE <TABLE>;`. By default, there is no mapping of `Types.DOUBLE` to `float`.

See [Hibernate: Found: float, expected: double precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524966/hibernate-found-float-expected-double-precision/13272074#13272074) for adding this mapping via extending the class `Oracle10gDialect`.