# Why does Oracle convert datatype double precision always to float(*)?

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, ddl

I have a table in a Oracle Database and the coresponding Entity in Java. Whenever I add a new column with datatype `double precision` it will end up as datatype `float(*)` in my table. And when I start my application with validating the entities against the database, it will stop with an exception.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
>   Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [my_col] in
>   table [my_table]; found [float (Types#FLOAT)], but expecting [double
>   precision (Types#DOUBLE)]

DDL that I execute: `ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD MY_COL double precision;`

**Entity:**

```
 //annotations etc..
public class MyTable{
    ....

    @Column(name = "MY_COL", precision = 99, scale = 99, nullable = false)
    private double myCol;

    ....
}
```

**What can I do so that Oracle inserts the column with the datatype double precision?**

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524966/hibernate-found-float-expected-double-precision? Perhaps it'll help.